# How to pass stream to Skype?

Tags: video, skype, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

Is it possible to pass arbitrary video stream to or from Skype? For example, can `VLC Player` simulate video source or sink?

Specifically, I would like to show my daughter some augmented reality objects, generated by [AR-media](http://www.inglobetechnologies.com/en/new_products/arplugin_max/info.php).

I would like universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need something that Skype recognises as a webcam, which I don't think is possible with VLC.

There's a freeware program called [SplitCam](http://www.splitcamera.com/) which will let you stream a variety of sources to Skype.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your OS, so I'm assuming Windows. You can use [ManyCam](http://download.manycam.com/feature#live_video_switcher) and select a video file to use as webcam source on Skype (or any other software). I have used it in the past and it works fine.

Comment: no longer free though

Answer (score 0):

screen sharing built in to Skype is a good and easy way to do it.

steps:(while call in progress)

> 1.click the blue camera button below the video.
>
> 2.choose,Share your screen (Share selection).
>
> 3.Resize the red selection box over your video, start screen sharing.

this would do the task for you.

for linux:

Webcam Studio.[link](http://www.ws4gl.org/)